# Waypoints.js with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-waypoints

I'm developing a wordpress site and I need to trigger the user scroll in order to fire different events and hide/show some images, so Waypoints.js is perfect for it.

However I've tried different attempts to make it work with no results. I add it as a function on functions.php file, like this:

```
function waypoints_method() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('waypoints', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/vendor/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'waypoints_method' );
```

And then in the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.waypoint').waypoint(function() {
            alert('You have scrolled to my waypoint.');
        });
}
```

The only thing I get it is to console.log when resizing the browser. So, what I need to do in order to make it work? Or, there is any alternative to Waypoints.js that I could use?

Thanks!

Comment: WordPress loads jQuery in "noconflict" mode, so you can't use $() unless it's inside an IIFE. Try changing your code to use `jQuery('.waypoint').waypoint(...)`

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code; I actually load jQuery this way an all the other jQuery scripts are working, so I guess it has nothing to do with it? Thank you anyway, @DaveRoss !

Comment: Are your paths correct? Do the files actually load correctly?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I think they do but don't really know, I'm not a php-wordpress expert, I guess Waypoints.js is working somehow but not properly if I can get the alert fired sometimes when resizing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) is using `$` to access jQuery, but with WordPress you need to refer to jQuery as `jQuery`.

I found that I had to use the [no framework version of Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) to get it working with WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck into the same issue for several hours today.

The solution is described - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76008972/21480817) (same issue on stack).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).