# Issues with waypoints.min.js / jquery.min

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-waypoints, visual-composer

I'm using WordPress and Visual Composer, when I edit Visual Composer Front Page, add new row then add Post Grid then stop working because of error javascript see screenshot, I wonder if anyone know about this?

[image]

Thanks,

Shaun.

Comment: can you provide the siteurl

Comment: It on localhost not live site yet.

Comment: can you share a smapshot where i can see this jquery library path

Comment: follow this this thread to fix this issue 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033374/waypoints-js-with-wordpress)